# CSS3 :target issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have 2 "links" which has to get a color when i click on them. But they need also be in a h1 tag.

Like this:

```
<div id="content" class="work">
    <h1 style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;"><a id="link-grafisk-design" href="#grafisk-design">Grafisk design</a></h1>
    <h1 style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</h1>
    <h1 style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; width:276px"><a id="link-webbdesign" href="#webbdesign">Webbdesign</a></h1>
</div>
```

But it wont change color when i click in one of them.
Here's the CSS

```css
#webbdesign:target ~ #link-webbdesign {
    color:#00A2FF;
}
```

Comment: And where's the element with the `id` of 'webdesign'?

Comment: "But they need also be in a h2 tag". I don't see any h2 tags in your code

Comment: the link has an id named link-webbdesign 
sorry meant h1 tag

Comment: But `#webdesign` won't link to anything with an `id` of `link-webdesign`.

Comment: This question is all too confusing for me to be confident that you understand how `:target` and anchor links work.

Comment: @BoltClock i'm trying to achieve the same effect from the tutorial
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/30/page-transitions-with-css3/

Answer (score 6):

That's not what [`:target` is for](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/). For styling the link you click on you should use `h1 a:active`.

```
h1 a:active {
     color:#00A2FF;
}
```

If you want the changed colour to persist until the user clicks something else, then use:

```
h1 a:focus,
h1 a:active {
    color: #00A2FF;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3168595)

Comment: i want to use target because i will work with transitions and other stuffs later on the same page

Comment: @Adib93: Do you want to style the link you click on, or do you want to style the section it leads to? `:active` is for styling the link itself, `:target` is for styling the section the link that was clicked goes to.

Comment: right now i just want to style the link, but i will use target for styling the section later. And i tried active and it only changed the color for a second, when the mouse was clicked but dissapers after i released

Comment: Using the `:active` and `focus` pseudo-classes/selectors will only style the element while those conditions are true; which, for mouse input, is usually only while the mouse-button is held down.

Comment: @David Thomas: Actually, using `:active` and `:focus` is an old trick to get "on click behaviour" with only CSS for things like drop-down menus http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/S8Kwq/ or accordions http://dabblet.com/gist/1728264 . You just need to add `tabindex="1"` and it persists until something else is clicked - I've updated my answer with a demo.

Comment: but it wont change unless you click on the other link "grafisk design" and vice versa....

i'm trying to do like the tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/30/page-transitions-with-css3/